# Javascript is not running

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This javascript code is supposed to switch when clicked an image to images from a folder within the html file folder.
After it gets to the last image, if you click again it resets to the first image.
Also there's a fade in and out effect on the appearing images.

It doesn't work and I suspect I wrote the path files to the images wrong somehow and the .attr doesn't change the src of the first image to the others.

Things to keep in mind = an extremely beginner programmer, just picked up html and css in about 2 days, I would appreciate any kind of help!

This is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imageName = ["head.jpg", "head3.jpg", "head4.jpg"]; 
    var indexNum = 0;

    $("#head1").click(function() {
        $("#head1").fadeOut(300, function() {
            $("#head1").attr("src", imageName[indexNum])";
            //$(indexNum).css("height=600px,width=1000px")
            indexNum++;
            if (indexNum > 2) {    
                indexNum = 0;
            }
            $("#head1").fadeIn(500);
        )};
    )};
)};
```

Comment: You can debug any script by using the console (press F12 in your browser). You have several syntax errors.

Comment: what is the purpose of the last `"` at the end of  `$("#head1").attr("src", imageName[indexNum])";`

Comment: Your problem is that you reset the indexNum = 0 in if statement, so it does what it suppose to do when you reach the last element in the array you reset your index to be 0 so it selects the first element from array again.

Comment: David, there is no purpose, it's a mistake

Comment: Why do people down vote questions like this? I'm up voting it.. WHY.. because SOF is for learning.. and he explained what the script is meant to do, had his own suspicions and also stated he is new to this... WHY down vote someone for trying to learn and being able to explain and show code on their first post....

Comment: @Mayhem I agree. Downvotes with no explanation are what is killing SO, but that's a conversation for Meta.

Comment: Mayhem I have to admit I had trouble putting the code to show as code on this post haha, it is my first. I appreciate the support!

Comment: user4559409... maybe so, but by suppying the code and taking the effort.. You had your problem solved asap. So welcome to SOF and glad to see a new user who done it right first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even thought this has been answered, here is a fiddle with your original code corrected. http://jsfiddle.net/goqz3coj/

Its better to see how your code should work instead of been giving a different code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imageName = ["head.jpg", "head3.jpg", "head4.jpg"]; 
    var indexNum = 0;

    $("#head1").click(function() {
        $("#head1").fadeOut(300, function() {
            $("#head1").attr("src", imageName[indexNum]);
            indexNum++;
            if (indexNum > 2) {    
                indexNum = 0;
            }
            $("#head1").fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
});
```

**SECOND VERSION**  Waits for image load before showing again...
http://jsfiddle.net/goqz3coj/2/

By simply using .load you can wait for the image to load and then show.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imageName = ["http://placehold.it/200x200", "http://placehold.it/300x300", "http://placehold.it/400x400"]; 
    var indexNum = 0;

    $("#head1").click(function() {
        $("#head1").fadeOut(300, function() {
            $( "#head1" ).load(function() {
                $("#head1").fadeIn(500);
              // Handler for .load() called.
            });
            $("#head1").attr("src", imageName[indexNum]);
            indexNum++;
            if (indexNum > 2) {    
                indexNum = 0;
            }
        });
    });
});
```

*Jonas Grumann* took your image urls as easier to show with actual images.

Comment: I agree on some degree. It will be easier for him to understand the answer, but I think we should also point them in the right direction in order to avoid him picking up some bad habits. I guess having both options is the best thing, like it happened here.

Comment: Of course, but for someone who is new to the field.. i like to keep it simple for them so they can continue without having to understand change. Once they understand the way the code works... Then its upto them to learn different methods and reasons.  But you get my thumbs up for show it simple for them and not giving them more than they need to see

Comment: Agreed, he now has both answers

Comment: A problem - when I click on the first image on the first time it fades out properly as it should, next it should load the first photo from the array and it doesn't load anything nor can click to keep it going.

Comment: I tried to switch the picture paths in the array to the links you used and it still load nothing instead of loading the first picture...

Comment: Are you still having these issues? Sorry as had to sleep last night lol

Answer (score 3):

You got a couple of errors in your code,
You swapped the closing ")" and "}" in the last two lines and you have a random " in the code.

Here's a working example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var imageName = ["http://placehold.it/200x200", "http://placehold.it/300x300", "http://placehold.it/400x400"]; 
    var indexNum = 0;

    $("#head1").click(function() {
        indexNum = (indexNum + 1) % imageName.length; // this will count 0,1,2,0,1,2,0,1,2... always looping through your images
        $(this).fadeOut(function() { //in this context, this refers to the #head, reading it from the DOM over and over again isn't efficient
            $(this).attr("src", imageName[indexNum]);
        }).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="head1" src="http://placehold.it/200x200" alt="">
```

Just a small note: Your script (and mine) don't take into account loading times, this means that it will probably  work fine on your computer, locally, but once you put it on a server, you will see the image fadeout, then fadein and still be the same image and then swap to the new image all of a sudden. This happens because it has some loading time. If you want to fix this you'll need some other events. Or you could load all images into the page and then just swap the one that is currently shown.

Comment: A question about the file path in the imagename = . Instead of putting a link I can just put a path to a folder like images/head.jpg, correct?

Comment: YEP.. You can link to "folder/image.jpg" yes.. as long as it is relative to your file.. as in on the same site/pc.. http:// = absolute url